# issue with package-info.java

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have generated webservice client proxy using wsdl in jdeveloper. I got all generated class and able to make a webservice call.

But when I try to patch these java files to production instance, the class file for package-info.java is not getting generated, so getting the exception while creating the jar file.

If i remove package-info.java class manually, getting the error saying, "Client received SOAP Fault from server : Failure in SDOSerializer.deserialize." . 
Is there anyway, that I can remove the package-info.java file and its dependencies, with out getting any error? or any other suggestions?

Comment: No, it can not be. until you chose to use different api for marshalling

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there anyway to get past the error "Client received SOAP Fault from server : Failure in SDOSerializer.deserialize." Please suggest.

Comment: you need to compile package-info.java and include it in your jar of generated classes

Comment: Hi Sohan, can you please let me know the solution. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @Sanjeev your comment helped me a lot ! I missed to commit the package-info.java which is already generated in stubs folder and so on deployed server, I got above errror. Thanks again!

Comment: @z21 glad that helped you.